# Azure app scale Error: Cannot change to the target SKU 'Free' because the Public Certificates count will exceed the new limit of '0'

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I want to scale my azure app service to F1-free and I'm getting the following error:

> "Cannot change to the target SKU 'Free' because the Public Certificates count will exceed the new limit of '0'".

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have custom domains + certificates on that web app? Based on the error, it sounds like that. Free doesn't support that scenario so it would give you an error like that.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I've removed the public certificate, and now it works.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have custom domains + certificates on that web app? Based on the error, it sounds like that. Free doesn't support that scenario so it would give you an error like that.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I've removed the public certificate, and now it works. Thanks for your help